With jquery simple upload, how do I receive the server reponse?
I'm using this library to upload PDF-files: https://github.com/kanety/jquery-simple-upload/tree/master. However, I cannot figure out a way to access the server reponse to the request, despite the response not being empty.
All received fields in upload:done etc. are either undefined or not filled with the server reponse. Is this even possible?
Best regards

It looks like you can get it from the upload:done event. The arguments passed to the event are file, index, data, status, xhrhttps://github.com/kanety/jquery-simple-upload/blob/master/src/simple-upload.js#L213C41-L213C72

From the documentation, use upload:done callback refer this.

All of the variables returned by this (file, index, data, status, xhr), as @evolutionxbox
listed, do only contain information about the file being uploaded, not the response of the server

@runningOnWaves https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/#jqXHR says that there should be responseText or responseXML on the xhr object?
